# Excluding RAM addresses in LD (GNU linker)

Tags: gcc, embedded, ld

Working on an ARM-based EVB, I've stumbled upon a defective memory location. Until the new EVB arrives:

What's the easiest way of telling LD to exclude specific RAM addresses or address ranges? Specifically, how to modify the linker script to achieve this?

Comment: Modify the linker scripts used by `ld`?

Comment: There must be a file with extension `*.ld`, you have to edit the address range in the SECTIONS of that file. As far as I know about address ranges in linker script file.

Comment: The "easiest" way may be to purposefully place a  buffer there that you never use (assuming your toolchain suports the `at()` `__attribute__`. (and your hardware doesn't lock up when writing the bad ram, since it will get zero initialized).  The right way, though, is to remove it from the map in the .ld file

Comment: It doesnt have to have the extension .ld but will have a SECTIONS entry so you can grep for that.  Without seeing your linker script it is not really possible to tell you what to change.  Yes the linker script can be used for this but because there are different ways to do it within that language (gnu ld linker script) there is no one generic answer, perhaps not even one answer for your specific script.

Comment: both the MEMORY area or the SECTIONS area or a combination of both can define where the valid ranges are, if you are trying to avoid one address or hole, that can get tricky as the linker really wants to put all the .text together and all the .data together (and others) as a default, so you would have to start defining objects by name.  I would work around the problem in other ways, get another eval board or use other hand tuned based tricks rather than this extreme.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the .ld script you can create some unused variable in this location. Not all compilers could support that, here you got example: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2829.htm. You just need to ensure that this variable is not optimized out or disable linking optimizations.